# Is Admin consent always required in an Azure AD Multi tenant environment?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

The environment is configured in a Multi-tenant way. 'AppName' is an App Registration within a common AD which was solely created to give access to users from different tenants to a single environment. For the sake of my description, call the multi-tenants AD1, AD2 and AD3.

This message is displayed when a user from one of these ADs (with no Admin privileges) logs in the first time.

> AppName needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant

Additionally in the application exception logging I can see the below error

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: "OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: 'access_denied'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'AADSTS650056: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the following: The client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, The admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, Check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant.

The premise is that for a user from AD1 to successfully access the environment, an Admin user from AD1 has to first login and grant admin access.
The "common AD" app registration is configured as following.

The Supported account types option in the App Registration is set as

> Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)

The only API Permission is as shown in the image below. The status "Granted for ...." only refers to the "common AD" where the tenant ID resides - it does not grant Admin consent to **any** AD.

[image: API Permission]

The technology being used in the code is ADAL.Net with OpenIDConnect. We are using the: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common (V1.0) endpoint.

In the snippet shown below, found within this [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) for the only API permission being set in our case.. 'Admin Consent Required' is set as 'No'.

[image: User.Read permission does not require Admin consent]

And that is what put me off. Why is the message/error popping up? Is the Admin consent **always** required because this is a multi tenant scenario? Does this Admin consent, sort of, create the trust between the common AD and the multi-tenant ADs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In case of multi-tenancy, admins are required to on-board their tenant. Only after the on-boarding process, users can sign-in. Also, the admin consent which is being shown in the screenshot is not related or dependent on type of tenancy, it is permission specific. App permissions and some delegated permissions require admin consent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am accepting it as the answer. may I add that there is a setting in Azure Portal / Active Directory / Enterprise Applications / User Settings, where you can allow Users from your domain to consent for themselves (at a user level).

Comment: Thanks for accepting this as the answer. Are you talking about "Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf" setting? This is by default set to Yes I think, and it will still need admin to onboard the tenant.

Comment: @RohanNevrikar Where can I find the document of this "onboarding process"? or does this "process" mean that the admin must try to sign in first, during sign-in, he/she then can grant (or deny) the consent?

Comment: @RickHayek Yes you are right, the onboarding process here means that admin need to sign in first, during which they can grant/deny admin consent, and only after this users will be able to sign in. You can refer to the 2nd link of this answer to read about the flow more.